# How to get the hostname for my site hosted by wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I got a link which is like www.example.com/wp-login.php where I can login using the given username and password but I can't connect with filezilla client using hostname as www.example.com or example.com or ftp.example.com or ftp://example.com. How do I find my hostname?

Comment: Please add more information. What kind of host service are you using? If you can name your hoster then it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

The hostname usually depends on you service hoster. You should login into your hosting services and usually you can get the information there. If you cant find it you may contact you hosting serive and ask for the right hostname.

Be aware you login data for the ftp services may be different to the service or wp login.

Answer (score 0):

ftp hostname depends on ftp configuration on server, if you have a dedicated server you can configure it.
If you use a hosting plan (bluehost,goddady etc) you should search for it on cpanel, on ftp section

Answer (score 0):

Your Wordpresses websites hostname is the domain name part of your URL - if that doesn't work either your provider has not correctly set up FTP or they are doing something non-standard (this is unlikely but possible for security and/or scalability reasons, but probably not best practice).

The only people who can help you are the company providing your hosting, as they have configured the FTP server.